# No scheduled commands are ready to run. Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, scheduler

I'm trying to run command every minute with scheduler but scheduler:run prints No scheduled commands are ready to run. message. As I understand, I don't need to set cronjob if I want to test shcedulder by run command. Any suggestions how to solve this issue are appreciated

My command:

```
/**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'print:log';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Print in log';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        info('message from command');
    }
```

Kernel.php

```
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\PrintLog',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('print:log')->everyMinute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as?

```
       protected $commands = [
            Commands\PrintLog::class,
        ];
    
        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            $schedule->command('print:log')->everyMinute();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this one not giving wanted results too :/

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand. Read docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler).

`schedule:run` command is for production - you must use it with cronjob on server

`schedule:work` command is for local development and testing. Run this command in terminal window and wait one minute - your scheduled job will be dispatched.